# My story is a mythological fantasy set in England in the 1700's. I have two characters, and my main one, dies. I don't know how to continue writing it

Tags: characters, perspective, death

As I mentioned in the title, my main character dies. I don't want to write it from my secondary character, because I feel as if that would feel weird for the readers, as they are used to my main character. How should I continue the perspective of the story after killing off my main character?

Comment: Asking what to write is off-topic here, but I'm sure there's a way this can be phrased in order to make it on topic. Something more general and technical, like, "How do I switch POVs after killing off the viewpoint character?"

Comment: Thanks You, I'll Edit It

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question is: Do you want your main character to continue telling the story?

If you do, make some changes in your writing that include some kind of loophole for your character to amazingly survive.

If not, make sure to build a likable secondary person for readers to follow through with the death of the original character.

If you want your story to continue, you could have a time jump to the main character's past where he/she is still alive or jump to the future in a different Point of view to explain what happens after the main character's death. Allegiant by Veronica Roth demonstrate the time jump of several years after the female heroines die in another person's POV.

This is only my suggestion so I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't really want to have a loophole where my main character survives, as that will seem to much of a plot device, and it's not that my character isn't written well, but it would feel as it would, if Harry Potter died, and the story continued from Hagrid's view. It would just seem off.

Comment: Then try to have your character walking through the land of the dead or have your character wake up in a different place and time. Do you want your character to live? Answer this and I might be able to provide more advice.

Comment: I don't know. I just kind of went with the flow of the story, so I went with it

Comment: The character controls the story but you are directing them to the right way. Going with the flow of the story is not a crime but it will create a author's block. Separate the story with Part 1 and 2. With Part 1 as the main character and Part 2 as the secondary character. Good luck.

Comment: Okay, thank you